Proof showing thermal noise of 2 resistors in series behave as a single noisy resistor

For the second part of this question, I came up with two slightly different answers? I believe it's the second one however I am not too sure which one would be the correct one.
First one:

Second one:
4KBT1R1+4KBT2R2 = 4KBTRt
T1R1 + T2R2 = TRt
Assume T = T1 = T2 (assumption from the term 'equilibrium')
R1 + R2 = Rt
Also, if the assumption that T = T1 = T2 is correct, What would be the course of action if the temperatures were not equal? (i.e not in equilibrium)

Simply, assuming both noise sources are uncorrelated, two voltage in series can be added. In this case, we can add the noise power \$4kTR_1\$ and \$4kTR_2\$, thus \$4kT(R_1+R_2)\$. If the resistors are in thermal equilibrium, then T is the same for both.
If both resistor are at different temperatures, then simply use the same formula but now use 2 different temperatures.
I've never encountered a situation where I've had to calculate noise from resistive elements with different temperatures though. At least in an IC, the safe assumption is that the whole chip have their thermal gradients settled, i.e. temperature is equal everywhere. During noise measurements I've always seen good agreement with simulations that assume all components to be at the same temperature.

Thought so. Appreciate it, thanks
